# Video camera for conferencing in large room

Tags: video, ms-office-communicator

We bit the bullet and setup Windows Communications Server 2007 based on recommendations here (thanks!) for a LAN based video conferencing solution. Now we are looking to connect the board rooms of our 2 offices to enable us to video conference between the two (connected via a single T1).

Any suggestions on a video camera we can permanently mount that can capture a room approx. 20'x40'?

We may also try to push audio through the connection as well, any suggestions on a mic?

We are thinking of connecting the camera to some sort of kiosk PC in the room running the Communicator client, so I'm guessing we'll need a USB/CAT5 extender for the device(s).

I don't really trust any of the local A/V folk to know much in the realm of video conferencing, so even if you don't have specific suggestions, I'd love to hear from anybody that has some experience in this area or can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this camera at a number of events and it is rather nice.  It was a Microsoft product and then Poycom bought it. Not inexpensive. [RoundTable](http://www.livemeetingplace.com/roundtable/?gclid=CKn54vKfop8CFQ975Qod3i4FTA)

One neat feature is that if the room is quiet, attendees  see the whole room but if a person speaks, the camera focuses on them.  Check the demo

Comment: Wow that is a very cool solution.